# Variable not in Scope Error Haskell for a simple function

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

For a task I need to implement a function in Haskell, and the first two parts of the definition are:

```
> collatz :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
> collatz x 0 = x
```

If I load it in ghci there's no error, but if I try to call it then this error occurs:

```
<interactive>:25:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: collatz :: Integer -> Integer -> t
```

My question is, what does this error means?
I use Visual Studio Code and the integrated Powershell.

Comment: How did you load this in `ghci`? Where did you define this?

Comment: I just reloaded it in the shell from Visual Studio Code

Comment: Sure you actually had the right file loaded in the first place? And saved it with the function before re-loading? You can use `:browse` to see what GHCi has actually loaded.

Comment: yep it loaded the right file

Comment: @Malone2409 Perhaps try `import`ing your module and see whether that works?